# Eliminar el elemento 6 y los tres primeros elementos del vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i,n;
    vector <int> v(10);
    cout<<"ingrese 10 numeros"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        v[i]=i+1;
    }
    //necesito borrar el elemento 6
    v.erase(v.6)//segun el pofe sirve para borrar elemento indicado pero no me sirve 
    //y tambien los tres primeros elementos
    v.pop_front()//esta sirve para borrar el primer elemento pero no se como utilizarlo
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<"-";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Edwin, en vez de poner comentarios en el codigo te recomiendo que lo expliques detalladamente en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Para preguntas tan sencillas, a mi me ayuda mucho [leer la documentación](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Y, por favor, investiga antes de hacer la pregunta. Llevas dos preguntas en cosa de una hora y las dos están íntimamente ligadas. Si te lo damos hecho no vas a aprender y eso es algo que vas a lamentar a la hora de los exámenes (que no vamos a estar ahí). En serio, revisa la documentación, pégate con el problema y no tengas prisa por solucionarlo... tener una base de papel en un lenguaje como C++ no es nada divertido

Comment: hola amigo, porfavor explica detalladamente que necesitas

Comment: si lo he intentado pero esa librería vector es rara y no he podido utilizarla bien lo único que ocupo en el código es eliminar el elemento 6 del vector y eliminar después los tres primeros elementos del vector y visualizar el resultado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que si lo usas de la siguiente forma funcionara, desconozco si hay alguna mas correcta, si es así espero me corrijan.

## Para borrar el sexto elemento

```
v.erase(v.begin()+5);
```

## Para los 3 primeros:

```
v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin()+3);
```

La funcion **v.pop_front()** si no me equivoco es para una lista y no para el vector

Comment: Tienes razón, creo que ahora seria correcto, corrígeme si me equivoco.@eferion

Comment: La primera opción sigue mal. Ahora borras el séptimo... Nunca está de más hacer una prueba antes de publicar la respuesta

Comment: Ahora sí que sí!